# How to bind an json value that has space in its name with variable

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable

```
var uniqueData = data[selectedIndex].values[0];
```

I want to bind it to differnt values  from a json dataset to extract the value

when I  do the follwoing it works fine

```
var elec_plants = uniqueData.Total;
console.log(elec_plants)
```

But there are some values with spaces inside such as

```
Main activity electricity and heat production: "1.4"
```

how can I bind it to uniqueData?

```
UniqueData.Main activity electricity and heat production
```

throws errors

Comment: to be clear, this has nothing to do with JSON. It's a javascript object, and you're simply adding a property to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uniqueData['Main activity electricity and heat production']
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in your case the value is not valid JavaScript identifier, so you have to use square brackets notation:

> "An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or
>   anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty
>   string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript
>   identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen,
>   or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square
>   bracket notation. This notation is also very useful when property
>   names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not
>   determined until runtime)."

You can have a look at this article: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)